# Cant access mainnet-beta (403 forbidden)

Tags: metaplex, nft, rpc, metaplex-js, mainnet

I'm trying to get a list of NFTs held by a wallet and display them using metaplex js. The problem is when I try to connect to mainnet-beta, I get a 403 forbidden error. I read that Solana restricts access to this and 403 means my IP is banned, but I tried from several different IPs and had no luck. Are there any alternative ways to access accounts on mainnet and view their NFTs?

Here is my code for reference:

```
  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState<any>(null)
  const getNFTs = async () => {

    console.log("Finding NFTs");
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"), "confirmed");
    const keypair = Keypair.generate();
  
    const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
    metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));
  
    const owner = new PublicKey("3kQG4UgztyTF9MnJwcKaCPFv5FD64Vk13YzxUrtWgrZn");
    const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({ owner: owner });
  
    console.log(allNFTs);
    setNfts(allNFTs)

  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching all NFTs for an owner is a pretty intensive query. The public RPC you are using (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com) is not designed for very large or frequent queries (see constraints [here](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#mainnet-beta)).

I suspect getting a free private RPC (e.g., QuickNode) would solve your problem. Just replace `clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta")` with your private RPC url, and I think you'll be in business! A list of free mainnet RPCs is available [here](https://solana.com/rpc).

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using react, so sure there are no leaks in your application that might be calling your `getNFTs` more than 1x.